# Python - Using Selenium to extract data from Webpage

Tags: python, list, selenium

I am trying to extract IP address information from a webpage using Selenium, here is a portion of the code

```
removals = []
ServerNames = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Microsoft') or contains(text(), 'Solaris') or contains(text(), 'Linux') or contains(text(), 'Server') or contains(text(), 'Windows') or contains(text(), 'AIX') or contains(text(), 'VMware') or contains(text(), 'ESX')]")
Backups = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), '|locationInherited=true')]")
ips = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), '10.') or contains(text(), '167.') or contains(text(), '170.') or contains(text(), '192.') or contains(text(), '172.') or contains(text(), '204.')]")
for x, y in itertools.zip_longest(ServerNames, Backups, fillvalue=''):
        x.click()
        ips
        y.click()
        ips
for ip in ips:
        removals.append(ip.text)
```

When a 'ServerNames' object is found and clicked, the webpage will display both the primary and backup IP addresses for that particular server, with that said,  need the script to:

1)Iterate through every found "ServerNames" object
2) Click on the object
3) Grab the associated Primary IP
4) Click on the associated "Backups" object found
5) Grab that IP as well

Then move on to the next ServerNames object and repeat these steps until all IP addresses for all severs have been extracted. I understand that the driver.find_elements method essentially create lists, so basically I need a way to alternate clicking & extracting data for each iteration through the lists. Thanks,

with the code above I get this error:

```
c:\Python35\Scripts>python Remedy2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Remedy2.py", line 73, in <module>
    y.click()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'click'
```

with this code:

```
for x in ServerNames:
        x.click()
        ips = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), '10.') or contains(text(), '167.') or contains(text(), '170.') or contains(text(), '192.') or contains(text(), '172.') or contains(text(), '204.')]")
        if Backups:
            for y in Backups:
                y.click()
                ips = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), '10.') or contains(text(), '167.') or contains(text(), '170.') or contains(text(), '192.') or contains(text(), '172.') or contains(text(), '204.')]")
```

I get a 'stale element error'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find the element again if the page changes after an action. The stale element erorr is caused probably because the element is no longer attached to the DOM. An approach is given below:

```
for i in range(len(ServerNames)):
        server = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Microsoft') or contains(text(), 'Solaris') or contains(text(), 'Linux') or contains(text(), 'Server') or contains(text(), 'Windows') or contains(text(), 'AIX') or contains(text(), 'VMware') or contains(text(), 'ESX')]")[i]
        server.click()
        ips = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), '10.') or contains(text(), '167.') or contains(text(), '170.') or contains(text(), '192.') or contains(text(), '172.') or contains(text(), '204.')]")
        if Backups:
            for j in range(len(Backups)):
                backup = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), '|locationInherited=true')]")[j]
                backup.click()
                ips = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), '10.') or contains(text(), '167.') or contains(text(), '170.') or contains(text(), '192.') or contains(text(), '172.') or contains(text(), '204.')]"
```

Comment: Excellent. Really appreciate the assistance.

Comment: Got this error: c:\Python35\Scripts>python Remedy2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Remedy2.py", line 75, in <module>
    server.click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

Comment: Make sure you are not missing the `[i]` at the end of line previous to `server.click()`

Comment: I see, thank you.. Just for my knowledge, what does the [i] and [j] tell the script to do?

Comment: `find_elements` methods returns a list of elements and `[i]` & `[j]` is used to assign the `i`th & `j`th element respectively to the variable.

Comment: I see thank you. I also got this error, any ideas? c:\Python35\Scripts>python Remedy2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Remedy2.py", line 79, in <module>
    backup = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), '|locationIn
herited=true')]")[j]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: It means there is a mismatch in the no. of elements in the Backups list you have defined at the top & the actual no. of elements on the page. `Backups` contains more elements. may be you can try with initlializing Backups just before the `if` clause.`

Comment: Amit, you've been a great help. really appreciate the knowledge you've shared and your time.

Comment: @I.T.Guy Glad to help!